# How do you make the actual nodes in Node Editor larger to read all of the information that's displayed in it?

Tags: node-editor, interface

I am actually surprised this ability is not present in Blender, as it is the most common thing that you can do in a lot of other programs.

**I don't want to scale the entire UI.**

I want to resize the actual nodes themselves so that I can read all the text and information that's displayed in them. Case in point:

[image: screenshot of nodes]

I hate how the nodes are so narrow to where a lot of information is cutoff with ellipses, like with *RemapAlphaTo...*, *VColorGroup*, and *BaseTex*. I want to be able to read everything listed in the node, not have it all shortened with ellipses. It doesn't seem possible to click on the edges and manually resize them to your liking.

If there's an option or ability to allow resizing them, I haven't found it within Blender. I haven't even found answers to it online; every result I've found is about someone wanting to know how to resize an image by using a node. That's definitely not what I'm looking for.

I don't know if I can provide a gif within a comment, so I assume I can only do it by editing my question. This is what I currently face:

[image: gif of node sizing problem]

EDIT: Okay, seeing people comment about how it IS possible is making me wonder what is going on with my setup of Blender. I will dig deeper.

Comment: Have you tried dragging from the corner?

Comment: Good news - you _can_ hover and click on the edges to resize the nodes, and zoom in by scrolling the mousewheel to make them larger.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, that only moves the window around. It does not resize them.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Hovering over their edges and clicking on them does not resize them, it only moves them around. Scrolling the mouse wheel zooms in onto the UI but does not make them larger to where, as I said in my question, they display all information written in them. I thought I was very specific about that in my question?

Comment: @ChiliBeef https://i.imgur.com/tUm0PEJ.mp4

Comment: I don't know why you're unable to resize via edge click - I am able to hover over any node edge or corner (until my cursor changes to a double arrow), then click and drag to resize to any dimensions I want (this is default behavior as far as I know.)

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I will see if I can provide a gif to show the complication I am facing.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I changed my question to show a gif of the problem I'm facing.

Comment: @Kuboå What the... okay, everyone commenting is making me realize that there must be something going on with my setup of Blender. I'm wondering if there is an add-on that's causing conflict.

Comment: @ChiliBeef An easy way to test if an addon or sth else is interfering would be to open Blender in "factory reset" form. You could download one of the daily zips (https://builder.blender.org/download/daily/), extract, there will be a folder with the version number there (for ex, "3.4" if that's what you've downloaded). Go in that folder, create a new folder named "config". That's it. Now it'll open with default settings with no addons enabled.

Comment: @Kuboå Thanks for the tip! Actually, what I did was save my current preferences and then loaded the factory defaults. Sure enough, I got that ability back. So, that helps me narrow it down as to what might be causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why I was having issues: In *Preferences > Keymap*, **Resize Node -- Left Mouse** was unchecked.